# Div tag around php code

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm trying to configure my database data that is being pulled with php to look like my homepage.

I can't figure out what I need to do.

This is for a project for school, and I have very limited knowledge on php.

Here is my php script.

```
<?php
include('mysql_connect.php');

$dbh = con();
foreach($dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `Product` WHERE `ProductType` = 'memory' ",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
$Pname = $row['ProductName'];        
$description = $row['description'];
$price = $row['ProductPrice'];
$ID = $row['ProductID']; 

     echo <div class="row">;
        echo <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">;
            echo <div class="thumbnail">;
            <img src="/var/www/html/Pictures/gigb75m_home.jpg" alt="">
                       echo "<div class="caption">";
                       echo "<h4 class="pull-right">$price</h4>";
                       echo "<h4>$Pname</h4>";
                       echo "<p>$description</p>";
                       echo "<p>$ID</p>";

}



?>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my index that has my desired results.

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="/var/www/html/Pictures/gigb75m_home.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4 class="pull-right">$74.99</h4>
                            <h4><a href="#">GIGABYTE GA-B75M</a>
                            </h4>
                            <p>Micro ATX, LGA 1155, Intel B75 Express Chipset, 2200MHz DDR3 (O.C.), SATA III (6Gb/s), 7.1-CH Audio, Gigabit LAN, USB 3.0 - GA-B75M-D3H</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Picture of homepage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZfK3.jpg

Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: that code is utterly riddled with syntax errors. `echo <div` is "echo lessthan div`, a complete illegal statement in php. you can't mix html and php like that either. html is NOT valid php, so even if all the garbage in the echo statements was "correct" (it's NOT), the img tag is an even worse error.

Comment: Hi @Brandan if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use single quote to echo content in your PHP script like this for instead :

```
 echo '<div class="row">';
```

The single quotes are used to explain that it's a string to show. You have to do the same for your other `echo` part.

**Or** you can escape the HTML part from the PHP and replace by vars inside it like this :

```
<?php
include('mysql_connect.php');

$dbh = con();
echo '<div class="row">';
foreach($dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `Product` WHERE `ProductType` = 'memory' ",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
$Pname = $row['ProductName'];        
$description = $row['description'];
$price = $row['ProductPrice'];
$ID = $row['ProductID']; 
?>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="/var/www/html/Pictures/gigb75m_home.jpg" alt="">
              <div class="caption">
                 <h4 class="pull-right"><?php echo $price; ?></h4>
                 <h4><?php echo $Pname; ?></h4>
                 <p>$description</p>
                 <p>$ID</p>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
<?php
}   
?>

</div>
```

Also you have to be careful about the row system of bootstrap to echo `col-md-4` inside a row, you can add 3 items like this per row. So you have to close and reopen a row each time you fetch 3 elements to get a correct HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use '.' for string concatinations.
For example:

```
echo '<h4 class="pull-right">' . $price . '</h4>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't supplied any information about your database, yet the first problem that's visible is your echo's

To output HTML through PHP you have to output pure strings.

An example for that would be **"****"**

In PHP when you want to connect different kinds of inputs like variables and "" or '' etc you connect them with a dot.

For example:

```
$string = ' hello3';
echo "Hello 1 ".' hello2 '.$string;
```

The outcome will be:

> Hello 1 hello2 hello3

I hope you got it the hang of it.